# How to Close a Browser with capybara?

Tags: capybara

In my code i am opening a browser as follow :-

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
include Capybara::DSL
describe 'Auro' do
specify "OMX Manual Order" do
visit 'https://omx.ordermotion.com/en/console.asp'
end
```

How can i close this browser?

Have Tried following ,but no luck:-

1. Capybara.current_session.driver.reset!
2. page.execute_script "window.close();"

Answer (score 3):

If you're only using selenium, then the following should work:

```
page.driver.quit
```

However, if you ever want to switch between different webdrivers, then you might want to add a condition or two.  This is what I use:

```
page.driver.quit unless (Capybara.current_driver == :webkit || Capybara.current_driver == :sauce)
```

:webkit refers to the headless capybara-webkit and :sauce refers to Sauce Labs, but you can use that code for whichever webdrivers you want to use.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try some of these

```
page.driver.browser.close
```

or

```
window = page.current_window
window.close
```

Keep in mind that if you have no other windows to switch to, an error will be raised

Comment: undefined local variable or method `page` for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this a shot:

```
page.execute_script "window.close();"
```

Comment: Was there an alert after that script was executed? If so, adding this should confirm the alert which should result in the window being closed:
"page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept"

Comment: There was no alert. Tried it still ,but no luck. Page remains open.